# JQuery val() returning empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm stuck on what seems like a trivial issue and I'm probably gonna kick myself for missing this..Anyway, my issue is I'm failing to get the value from a text field.

**HTML:**

```
<form>
        <label for="">Enter Username:</label>
        <input id="usernameText" type="text" size="30" />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Generate" onclick="generateQuery(); return     false;" />
</form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var username = $("#usernameText").val();

        function generateQuery(){

            alert(username);

        }
</script>
```

I did the following `if (jQuery) {..` and made sure JQuery is loaded.

In the alert it displays an empty dialog box.

If I included the `$(document).ready();` into my script the function `generateQuery` does not get called. Any idea why..?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var username = $("#usernameText").val();

        function generateQuery(){

            alert(username);

        }
    });     
</script>
```

Comment: @PSR: I have, I mentioned it in the notes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assign your variable within the function.

```
function generateQuery(){
  var username = $("#usernameText").val();
  alert(username);
}
```

As for your other question, *"If I included the $(document).ready(); into my script the function generate does not get called. Any idea why..?"*

This happens because of scope. You wrap `generateQuery` inside an anonymous function when you add a `document.ready` handler, and therefore it's not visible to your `button onclick="generateQuery()"` code.

Answer (score 3):

Here it will call while the page is loading.So whenever the page is loading the text box is empty.Try to write within a function.

```
function generateQuery(){
  var username = $("#usernameText").val();
  alert(username);
}
```

When you write  in `document.ready` it will cal;l while the page is loading.If you need the value of username then call explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

The value is being derived the first time through.  So when the page is first loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function generateQuery(){
            var username = $("#usernameText").val();
            alert(username);

        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are defining the function  you have to call the function in order to get it run use this `generateQuery();` line to call your function.

Answer (score -1):

where are you calling the function????

i think you need:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
      generateQuery();


    });     

function generateQuery(){
  var username = $("#usernameText").val();
            alert(username);

        }
</script>
```

Comment: It's being called onchange of the input field.